# show each word in one line and characters near them

Tags: php

i want to explode one phrase from textarea and near the words , number of characters

```
$char = $_POST['textarea'];
        print_r (explode ( " " ,$char));
        for($i = 0 ; $i<count($char) ;$i++)
        {
        echo $char . " - " . strlen($char) . "<br>" ;
        }
```

it displays : Array ( [0] => hello [1] => there ) hello there - 11
i want one line for each word

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$char = explode ( " " ,$char);
$char[$i] . " - " . strlen($char[$i])."<br>";
```

Comment: half correct. it should print only h-1 for $_POST['textarea']="hello there" :-) He has not saved the exploded array in $char as well.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the code a bit. What you're missing is, you're printing the $char exploding, but not storing it. Corrected code below:

```
$char = $_POST['textarea'];
    print_r (explode ( " " ,$char));
    $char = explode(" ",$char);     // I've added this line
    for($i = 0 ; $i<count($char) ;$i++)
    {
      echo $char[$i] . " - " . strlen($char[$i]) . "<br>" ; //We are printing $i'th string of $char, as $char is an array of strings now.
    }
```

Comment: yes ,you're so right , i didn't storing that char... i remove the printr explode because i don't need it . it works now , but everytime ,after the last words and numbers of characters , it appear - 0 , like if it's another word with 0 characters

Comment: $char = rtrim($char); // this will remove trailing spaces. 
add this line before $char = explode(" ",$char);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure on what your question is, but if you're using 
 it should break to a new line in HTML. If you are using the console or a plain text webpage then you will have to append "\n"